# understand some complex git procedure

Tags: git

I am working in a open-source software with a lot of people and I am assigned to solve a pull request.

Another contributor initially worked on a new feature on his own fork, now the pull request said "This branch has conflicts that must be resolved" and github indicate the following command line to merge the conflict.

1. From your project repository, check out a new branch and test
   the changes.

   ```
   git checkout -b others-master-branch master
   ```

   I know `git checkout -b branch-name`, but here what does the last parameter `master` stand for?

   ```
   git pull https://github.com/username/projectname.git master
   ```

   What does this mean then? filling content to the new branch from the master branch of the username?
2. Merge the changes and update on GitHub.

   ```
   git checkout master  
   git merge --no-ff others-master-branch  
   git push origin master
   ```

question: Where could possibly the conflict come from?

Comment: Regarding question 3: check out [this article](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/ebook/en/command-line/advanced-topics/merge-conflicts) - and at least the section "How a Merge Conflict Occurs"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding question 1

`git help checkout` answers the first question. `git checkout -b A B` is the same as `git branch A B ; git checkout A`: it creates a new branch `A` which points to the same commit as branch `B`.

In this example, you are creating a new branch `others-master-branch` which points to the commit currently pointed to by `master`, and will also checkout that new branch.

`git pull ... master` then is the same as `git fetch someorigin/master ; git merge someorigin/master`, assuming `someorigin` points to the URL you gave, i.e. it fetches the current `master` from the URL and merges it into your own current branch (`others-master-branch` at the moment).

This will tell you if there are unsolvable problems during the merge, and if the automated tests run fine afterwards. You can "roll back" anytime by simply deleting `others-master-branch` and you have zero chance to do any harm to your repository.

### Regarding question 2

Since you have done all the good work of merging into your "throw-away" branch `others-master-branch`, you can now simply merge that into your current master (which will be a fast-forward-merge, i.e., mere book-keeping) and then push it upstream.

### How can a merge conflict occur

You got a link to answer that in one of the comments below your question, and google will throw up lots of other good pages surrounding this topic.

In short: Most conflicts occur when lines in close vincinity inside a file have been edited in both sides of the merge. `git` will be unable to guess which of the edits is incorrect and leaves it up to you. They are usually not a cause for alarm (unless they span dozens or hundreds of lines), but standard business when merging.